# Qiskit pulse-level simulation

Tags: qiskit

I am looking to investigate qubits' response to pulses - the kind the hardware will actually create when gates are implemented.

Although there are many simulation capabilities in Qiskit, most of them simulate abstract gate implementations

Are there any modules in Qiskit that have the ability to simulate continuous-time dynamics of qubits? Links to working examples would be of great help, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

This capability is supported (although it is a bit basic), have a look at [this](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits_advanced/10_pulse_simulator_backend_model.html). Also worth having a look at is [Qiskit Dynamics](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-dynamics) which is a high-performance differentiable continuous dynamics simulator which will replace the existing pulse simulator shortly.

Comment: When this integration happens soon, as you say, does that mean the Ignis deprecation will be resolved? Will qiskis_dynamics be under Aer or Terra?